# Multiplying width or height by a number yields 0 in Processing

Tags: processing

In Processing, I keep getting 0 when I multiply `width` or `height` by a number. For example:

```java
int x = width*2;
```

I get `x = 0`. Why?

When you define a size in processing, `width` and `height` are automatically assigned (example `size(500,500)`). `width` and `height` are 500 in this case.

Comment: Then width is equal to 0. There is no code you are providing and the only way that you can get `x = 0` is if `width=0` in this context, assuming it is a whole number such as `int` and not a floating point number. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We don't even know what type `width` is. What if it's a floating point with a value less than 0.5?

Comment: probably you are doing before size calculation is done

Answer (score 0):

Note that `width` and `height` only have values **after** you call the `size()` function. (Or if you don't call the `size()` function, after `setup()` is called.)

That can be a problem if you do stuff before calling the `size()` function, such as at the beginning of your sketch:

```java
//this happens before the size() function is called!
int x = width*2;

void setup(){
   size(500, 500);
}
```

The solution is to put the **declaration** of sketch-level variables at the top of your sketch, but only do their **initialization** after calling the `size()` function:

```java
int x;

void setup(){
   size(500, 500);
   x = width*2;
}
```

This could also be caused if you try to define your own `width` and `height` variables:

```java
//don't do this!
int width;
int height;

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
  println(width);
}
```

Don't do this! Just use the `width` and `height` variables that Processing has already declared for you.

More generally, as you've seen, questions tend to be closed pretty quickly if people can't reproduce your problem. Although you did include the fact that you're using Processing, you'll have better luck in the future if you include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to see the problem ourselves. The code I've posted in this answer is a good example of the type of thing you should include in your questions in the future, that way they don't get closed.